# Vue Jest Framework | Uncovered lines are show as invalid

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, ts-jest, babel-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I am using jest framework for vue.js unit test cases. My issue is my file lines of code is 31. But showing uncovered line is 39, 40. Is there any issue in config related things.

[image]

[image]

What is the issue here. I am facing this issue in all my .vue files. How to rectify this

Answer (score 0):

```
"mapCoverage": true
```

Add this link in your jest.config.json file, then try it will work.